# How to make a 2 way relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to set up the relation between 2 Models so when loading the hasMany relation, the belongsTo relation is automaticly set to the caller/parent?

We run in to a memmory issue when using a save-trigger on the product, that loaded in a new copy of the order, with a new copy of each products.
So if an order had 100 products, and trying to loop over the order->products->order->products it loaded 101 orders with total 10100 products.

one way to solve it was to use the setRelation() to set the belongsTo relation, in the loop in the controller.

I'd prefer if there was a way to set that relation from the Model instead.

```
<?php
class Order extends Model {
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

    public function updateTotals() {
        foreach ($this->products as $product) {
            // code
        }
        $this->save();
    }
}

class Product extends Model {
    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::updated(function (Product $product) {
            $product->order->updateTotals();
        });
    }
}

class OrderController extends Controller {
    public function postView(UserOrderSaveRequest $request) {
        $order = $request->getOrder();
        foreach ($order->products as $product) {
            $product->setRelation('order', $order);
            // code
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**
Test i used to test the answer

```
// tinker function to fetch the first order
$o = Order();

// load 2 products
$o->products[0];
$o->products[1];

// Set relation
$o->products[0]->setRelation('order', $o);
$o->products[1]->setRelation('order', $o);

// load 2 products orders
$o->products[0]->order;
$o->products[1]->order;

// Test 1 (true if setRelation was used)
// (false in @Bilal Maqsood answer)
$o === $o->products[0]->order;

// Test 2 (true if setRelation was used)
// (true in @Bilal Maqsood answer)
$o->products[1]->order === $o->products[0]->order;

// Test 3 (false?)
$o->products[1]->order->products[0] === $o->products[0]->order->prodcuts[0]
```

Comment: Are you talking about many to many relationship ?

Comment: No a one to many, one side using the hasMany() and the other using betlongsTo()

Comment: I want $order->products->order be the same object as $order, and not another copy in the memory, as that eats memory exponential

Comment: Why don't you use n attribut in the Order model where to put the total that you want then when you add another product update just the attribute not looping over all the existing products in the Order : `public function updateTotals($product) {
        $total += $product->price ; // Or what ever yoou have to do :)
        $this->save();
    }`

Comment: This is nice thing to do for optimal resource usage, but actually I don't know about the problem and I hope other people here may provide you some way

Comment: @Maraboc when adding products, we call the updateTotals() one after, but the trigger is used when products are changed (static::updated), and  updateTotals() as in plural, handle multiple values, and when a product change some of them changes, there may be a "buy 3 pay for 2" involved that make it easier to just loop over all of them. In the exemple, moving the updateTotals() after the loop whould have worked, but the product->save() trigger is needed on other places in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Update you Product model code like

```html
class Product extends Model {

    protected $with = ['order'];

  public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
  }

}
```

the `$with` property load the defined relations for each record of product.

Comment: Adding the "with", lower the number of order copies in the memory, from 101 down to 2, still more then the setRelation() version that only got one, but alot better.